# Yii2 rest extra fields

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2

When using GET to list records the extraField that is included displays the correct value - rate_increase is the extra field.

```
{
    "reseller_rateref": 263756,
    "rate_increase": "50.00",
    ...
},
```

Model

```
class ResellerRateResource extends ResellerRate
{
public $rate_increase;
/*
 * @return $fields array Filtered fields for API presentation
 */
public function fields()
{
    $fields = array_merge(parent::fields(), ['rate_increase']);

    return $fields;
}
```

Query to fetch data:

```
 $query = $model::find()
                ->leftJoin('reseller_config', 'reseller_rate.resellerref = reseller_config.resellerref')
                ->select('reseller_rate.*, reseller_config.rate_increase AS rate_increase');
```

However when viewing an individual record it is always displayed as null. Anyone got any idea why?

Comment: no we don't, as you provided no information

Comment: that better....

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this line is wrong:

```
$fields = array_merge(parent::fields(), ['rate_increase']);
```

What is `['rate_increase']` ? An array you just defined, holding a string value.

I think you need some `$variable['rate_increase']` and then it will probably work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know `fields` only used for viewing purpose to hide sensitive information. But if you have any dynamic attribute in your custom query you can use attribute function to get the value of the attribute:

```
function attributes() {
   $attrs = parent::attributes(); // get all the attributes of the current model

   $attrs[] = 'rate_increase';
   return $attrs;

}
```

Now when ever you have a value in `rate_increase` column you will get the value eg: `$model->rate_increase`;

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#attributes()-detail